# Use PhantomJS to pre compile handlebars template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js, phantomjs

I have a rails application as back end and a BackboneJS application as front end. BackboneJS app starts with rails server. Now, I have a problem of search engine indexing pages of my application, which I tried to solve with phantomjs [I user [this](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem) gem]. I wrote a before_filter in application controller like this:

```
  def phantom_response
    if params["_escaped_fragment_"].present?
      url = "#{request.base_url}/#!#{params["_escaped_fragment_"]}"
      output = Phantomjs.run('/lib/assets/get_page.js', url)
      render :text => output
   end
end
```

And my get_page.js looks like this:

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
    page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
    page.open(phantom.args[0], function (d) {
       var body = page.evaluate(function(s) {
       return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
       }, '#provider_details_tpl');
    console.log(body);
    phantom.exit();
    });
```

The element with "provider_details_tpl" contains a handlebars template.

But phantomjs returns just my template without precompilation. Can you help me?